# Google Chrome get stuck when the range slider disable in it's change function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome

This problem only on Google Chrome Browser.
The HTML code is.

```
<input type="button" value="one" id="btnOne"><br/>
<input type="range" class="rangeSliderOne" min="1" max="5" id="DR" name="DROne" value="0" />
 <input type="button" value="two" id="btnTwo"><br/>
 <input type="checkbox" value="one" id="chkBox" ><br/>
 <input type="text" value="test" id="txtBox" style="display:none" > <br/>
```

Then I wanna disable the range slider when the slider Change. 
So i wrote a jQuery.

```
$('#btnOne').prop('disabled',true);
$('#DR').change(function(){
$('#btnOne').prop('disabled', false);
 $('#DR').attr("disabled", "disabled"); 
});

$('#chkBox').click(function() {
    $("#txtBox").toggle(this.checked);
});
```

when this execute in the Mozilla Firefox Browser it will work. but in the case of Google Chrome after disabling the range slider the browser get stuck. even we can't inspect the element on the browser. please help me to find a nice solution.kindly replay fast as possible. pls click here: http://jsfiddle.net/XNyMj/

Comment: You should file a bug anyway.  http://crbug.com/

Answer (score 0):

it is causing conflicts because when your code sets attr to your slider #DR to be disabled, it is considered as another event of "change" and triggers itself hence bring it to infinite loop. What you can do is either use another event listener or `use remove() instead of attr("disabled", "disabled")`; not sure what you want to achieve eventually but there should be other ways to do this. I know your code works on FF, they are of different fault-tolerance level. Also you may want to change this `$("#txtBox").toggle(this.checked); to $("#txtBox").toggle("slow");` it's kind of confusion too.